# argparse add mandatory argument, possibly without add_subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

Following is the code snippet -

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#External Modules
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', dest='FOO_OPTION', help='builds foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar', action='store_true', dest='BAR_OPTION', help='builds bar')
parser.add_argument('--xyz', action='store_true', dest='XyZ_OPTION', help='builds xyz')
```

Invoking the command

```
program.py --foo
program.py --bar 
program.py --xyz
```

works perfectly.

However, there is another mandatory arguement for --foo like

```
program.py --foo -d /usr/local/include
```

This additional arguement is just for --foo. How can this be achieved in the easiest possible way?

Comment: There isn't a mechanism in `argparse` to do this.  You need to test for this after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) argument, with a caveat.

For example,

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.foo)
```

Then, `python program.py --foo bar baz` gives `['bar', 'baz']`.

The caveat is that you couldn't use `-d` as a value for foo because of the dash.

Comment: Or just the default `store` and `nargs`, so that `--foo` requires one argument.  `args.foo` will be the default `None` if not provided.

Comment: will using add_subparsers help? My only concern with add_subparsers is that because of just one argument ( foo ) , all other arguements ( bar and xyz ) will have to be changed. Is my understanding correct?